# how to scroll accordion to top with this code

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ok, I click on a tab and it goes to the top of the page, it's an up scroll.

view image please.

I'm new to jquery and want to build from the code I'm exposing here.

[tab accordions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGUqV.jpg)

my code is jquery :

```
$(function() {
    $(".accordion-header").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dis = $(this);
        var acr_box = dis.closest(".accordion");
        if(!dis.hasClass("active-accordion")){
            acr_box.find(".accordion-header").removeClass("active-accordion");
            dis.addClass("active-accordion");
            acr_box.find(".accordion-content").stop(true,true).hide();
            dis.next().stop(true,true).show("scale", 1000);


        }  
    });
});
```

And HTML is :

```
<div class="accordion-box">
    <a id="contact" href="" class="accordion-header">COURRIEL</a>
    <div class="accordion-content" id="acrd_1000">
        <div class="accordion-content-flex">
            <div style="overflow:hidden"><?php include("/include/sendform-inc.php"); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS code is :

```
.accordion {
    color: white;
    width: 86%;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    max-width: 90%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:22px;
    font-weight: 900;
}

a.accordion-header.active-accordion {
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 14, 26,0.9), rgba(0, 128, 255,0.9), rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.9));
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;  border-radius:0;
    border-top-left-radius:0.7em;
    border-top-right-radius:0.7em;
    filter: grayscale(0%);
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.92);
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* ajout avec le background body */
}

.accordion-content {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -2px;
    border-top: solid 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-left: solid 1px #333;
    border-bottom: double 1px #333;
    border-right: solid 1px #333;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 2em;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 2em;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 14, 26,.95), rgba(0, 128, 255,.95), rgba(44, 62, 80, .95));
    padding: 22px;
    box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    overflow:hidden;
}
a.accordion-header {
    display: block;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(0, 14, 26,0.9), rgba(0, 128, 255,0.9), rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.9));

    background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(19, 24, 25, 0.96), rgba(0, 128, 255,0.9), rgba(36, 60, 55, 0.96));

    font-family: Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 0.7em;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    margin-top:15px;
    border: 1px solid #5B97FF;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.92);
}
.accordion-content-flex {
    height: 100%;
    /* display: flex; */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
a.accordion-header:after {
    content: '\25ba';
    color: #2bc;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-top: 0; 
    font-size: 16px;
}
a.accordion-header.active-accordion:after {
    content: '\25bc';
    color: #2bc;
}
```

Works fine but I want to scroll tab active header to the top of the window.

I want to modify my javascript as simple as possible to add the scroll, an example would be appreciated compared to the code above..

sorry, my English is basic and I translate with Google.

Comment: *I want to add the active header scroll to the top of the window.* What do you mean with this?

Comment: when I click on the tab it scrolls up.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Each **accordion-header** will need a unique ID. You can't duplicate IDs anyway. Then at the end of your click handler add **location.href = "#" + dis.id;** this will redirect the browser to that part of the page, essentially moving it up.

There are caveats though as the page BELOW the accordions needs some additional space to allow for the section to be shown at the top.

```
$(function() {
    $(".accordion-header").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var dis = $(this);
        var acr_box = dis.closest(".accordion");
        if(!dis.hasClass("active-accordion")){
            acr_box.find(".accordion-header").removeClass("active-accordion");
            dis.addClass("active-accordion");
            acr_box.find(".accordion-content").stop(true,true).hide();
            dis.next().stop(true,true).show("scale", 1000);
            location.href = "#" + dis.id;

        }  
    });
});
```